# Setting a variable depending on the OptionButton selected in the Frame

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I've got a Frame with 2 OptionButtons, only one of which can be selected.
I'm trying to create a variable to use later in the code which will return the OptionButton selected.

```
Dim MyVar as String
    MyVar = If OptionButton1.Value = True then "Button1"
    Else
        "Button2"
End If
```

Later in the code I intend to call MyVar, but I don't know if variables can be determined based on an If statement.

Can someone help me to write a code which will return MyVar? Is it even possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `IIf` statement:

```
MyVar = IIf(OptionButton1.Value = True, "Button1", "Button2")
```

Comment: I mean wow! Thank you. I've not even come across ```IIf``` in my searching. Thank you again.